# How to get available virtual and physical memory size under Mono?

Tags: .net, mono, clr

Is there any way to get *available* virtual and physical memory size when running under Mono?

Comment: Did you find an answer? A year on and no replies...

Comment: Mono is not a "wait for a year" kind of project.  If you have the itch then you can scratch it, they are waiting for your patch to [this file](https://github.com/mono/mono-basic/blob/master/vbruntime/Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices/ComputerInfo.vb).

Answer (score 3):

You could use this implementation of the ["free" command](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) (UNIX) to find out used and available physical memory (it is the best option IMHO):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace FreeCSharp
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FreeCSharp free = new FreeCSharp();
            free.GetValues();

            long buffersPlusCached = free.Buffers + free.Cached;
            long mainUsed = free.MemTotal - free.MemFree;

            // What you would get from free command:
            Console.WriteLine("-/+ buffers/cache:    {0}     {1}", (mainUsed - buffersPlusCached), (free.MemFree + buffersPlusCached));

            // What means:
            Console.WriteLine("Used physical memory: {0} kB", mainUsed - buffersPlusCached);
            Console.WriteLine("Available physical memory: {0} kB", free.MemFree + buffersPlusCached);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// FreeCSharp: quick implementation of free command (kind of) using C#
    /// </summary>
    public class FreeCSharp
    {
        public long MemTotal { get; private set; }
        public long MemFree { get; private set; }
        public long Buffers { get; private set; }
        public long Cached { get; private set; }

        public void GetValues()
        {
            string[] memInfoLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"/proc/meminfo");

            MemInfoMatch[] memInfoMatches =
            {
                new MemInfoMatch(@"^Buffers:\s+(\d+)", value => Buffers = Convert.ToInt64(value)),
                new MemInfoMatch(@"^Cached:\s+(\d+)", value => Cached = Convert.ToInt64(value)),
                new MemInfoMatch(@"^MemFree:\s+(\d+)", value => MemFree = Convert.ToInt64(value)),
                new MemInfoMatch(@"^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)", value => MemTotal = Convert.ToInt64(value))
            };

            foreach (string memInfoLine in memInfoLines)
            {
                foreach (MemInfoMatch memInfoMatch in memInfoMatches)
                {
                    Match match = memInfoMatch.regex.Match(memInfoLine);
                    if (match.Groups[1].Success)
                    {
                        string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
                        memInfoMatch.updateValue(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class MemInfoMatch
        {
            public Regex regex;
            public Action<string> updateValue;

            public MemInfoMatch(string pattern, Action<string> update)
            {
                this.regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
                this.updateValue = update;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it could be used [sysconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sysconf.html) (UNIX) to get the currently available pages of physical memory. This value depends on how many data the OS has cached, because of that, you should execute `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` before running this code:

```
using System;
using Mono.Unix.Native;

OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
PlatformID pid = os.Platform;
if (pid == PlatformID.Unix || pid == PlatformID.MacOSX) {
    long pages = Syscall.sysconf (SysconfName._SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = Syscall.sysconf (SysconfName._SC_PAGESIZE);
    Console.WriteLine("The number of currently available pages of physical memory: {0}, Size of a page in bytes: {1} bytes", pages, page_size);
    Console.WriteLine("Mem: {0} bytes", pages * page_size);
 }
```

Comment: The question is about _available_ amount, not total.

Comment: Thanks @Gooseman, a bit of noise in your answer which was misleading. I edited to make it simpler to show you're answering the OP question. Its not an ideal solution (i.e. reading from file system) but still a valid answer.

Comment: @JaredBroad Thank you very much, I've just edited my answer. I think the OP downvoted it, so I do not think he/she liked it at all. Anyhow, I will leave it here just in case it could help someone in the future. Next time, I should sleep a few hours before answering questions :P

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use much Mono, but have you tried looking through the [Mono Profiler](http://mono-project.com/Profiler) logs? I know they show physical memory, but i'm not sure about virtual...

Call me curious, but why do you need these? If you are having problems with memory usage in your app, there are plenty of [different techniques](http://andrewfray.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/reducing-memory-usage-in-unity-c-and-netmono/) you can use to help reduce it...

Edit: Doing a look around, there really isn't a mono specific way to gather it... However, depending on how you are running your application, you can still access the current process object in C#

```
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
var physicalMemory = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
var virtualMemory = currentProcess.PeakVirtualMemorySize64;
```

Then just use/return those as you see fit.

source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakvirtualmemorysize64%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: QuantConnect.com runs user-code and tracks the total memory usage so the machine doesn't run out of RAM. At the moment we cap it to a fixed 1024MB but want to allow the user to use the full RAM available on the machine --> So I need to dynamically know the remaining RAM available.

Comment: Doesn't mono (or c# for that matter) already monitor its own memory/RAM usage? Maybe i'm not fully understanding what you mean when you say "user-code"...

Comment: This is for my telemetry system... report any crashes of the application and related system data.

Comment: ahh ok. that makes more sense now. Thanks for the clarification. See if my edit helps you at all...